# Compiling msys make for compatibility with Mozilla's msys make

Tags: winapi, makefile, mozilla, msys

Running on Windows 7 with msys installed along with gcc and the source for GNU make 3.81.

In an msys bash shell I run ./confgure which enables both WINDOWS32 and HAVE_DOS_PATHS
Then running make produces an executable which reports 'This program built for i686-pc-mingw32'
If I then copy the resulting .exe into the /mozilla/build/msys/bin folder, make fails, claiming it cannot find files. The locally built version is ~2.3MB as compared to the ~153KB for the Mozilla version.

Can anyone tell me how the Mozilla crew builds their version of make for Windows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you'll find the [source](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-build/) to the [mozillabuild](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MozillaBuild) package helpful.

Comment: Neil, many thanks. I simply could not find the source. Here's some additional info from TedM@Mozilla: The
packages and build scripts are all here:
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-build/

It looks like we do compile make from source:
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-build/file/ae3600fddd4b/make-3.81.90.tar.bz2

with just this patch applied:
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-build/file/ae3600fddd4b/make-msys.patch

We trigger the build from this script:
http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-build/file/ae3600fddd4b/packageit-msys.sh#l34